# Can I use a Firebase app ID that was accidentally deleted by another user in my project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

In my Firebase project "katnissai", the app "katniss" was accidentally deleted by another user in the project. I was wondering, would I be able to possibly use this ID once again, or is it permanently gone due to the Firebase terms? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot reuse the Firebase App ID once it has been deleted ([the app is permanently erased](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7047853?hl=en)) and the App ID is automatically generated by Firebase, it means you cannot recreate it. Instead create a new app with the same name and use the App ID it created.